# Make rule for message in mail.app

Tags: mail.app, mail-rules

Is there a way to create a mailbox rule based on the currently highlighted message in mail.app? OSX 10.8.5

I want to create a rule from the application rather than have to go to Mail -> Preferences -> rules and create it there.

Comment: Please explain further what you want to do with the rule and message

Comment: something like a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: That would do I guess.